# Automatic locking/unlocking using scope in C++ (from C# background)

Tags: c++, exception

I've been using C# for the last few years and I am currently bug fixing in C++.
In C# I could use lock on an object to make my code thread safe with:

```
lock(lockObject)
{
    // Do some work
}
```

This would unlock the lockOject if there was an exception within the `// Do some work`

Is there something similar in C++? At the moment I can think of either:

```
// Code
{
    AutoLock lock(lockObject);
    // Do some work
}
// More Code
```

But I don't like the curly braces just to scope my `AutoLock`. At the moment I'm doing:

```
AutoLock lock(lockObject);
// Do some work
lock.Unlock();
```

And letting exception unwinding release the lock if there's an exception in `//Do some work`.

What I'm doing at the moment works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way, thanks.

Comment: _But I don't like the curly braces just to scope my `AutoLock`._  Aside from their placement, how are they that different from what is done in C#?

Comment: With C#'s `using(..){...}` and `lock(...){...}` you can see what's going on. It just feels wrong to me to just have empty `{...}` to create a local scope to make `Autolock` destruct.

Comment: That makes sense.  One advantage of the C++ way of doing things is you only need one scope to clean up multiple locks; if I recall correctly, in C# you can end up with things like `lock(m0) { lock(m1) { lock(m2) { } } }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I don't like the curly braces just to scope my `AutoLock`.

That's how it's done in C++.

Note that you don't need to have a separate scope block for each `AutoLock`; the following is fine too:

```
{
    AutoLock lock1;
    AutoLock lock2;
    // more code goes here
} // lock2 gets destroyed, then lock1 gets destroyed
```

It doesn't have to be a separate scope block either; if you are locking something in a function and don't need it to be unlocked until the function returns, then you can simply use the function scope to constrain the lock . Likewise, if you are locking something during each iteration in a loop block, you can use the loop's scope block to constrain the lock.

Your approach of manually unlocking the mutex when you are done with it is fine, but it's not idiomatic C++ and isn't as clear.  It makes it harder to figure out where the mutex is unlocked (not much harder, perhaps, but harder than it needs to be).

Comment: Re: Manual unlocking. True, it wasn't an ideal choice. I have used smart pointers for interfaces which let you `.Release()` but will auto release when out of scope. 
It has been quite a while since I was coding in C++, I may have forgotten/missed something that fits what I was after. Hence this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your second version is just fine. Consider splitting your method if you have too many braces that are just for scoped locking. Read up on [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), that is the general pattern behind this technique, and it can be applied to every kind of resource management.

Comment: Thanks for the link on `RAII`, I'm now looking at smart pointers to protect a block of memory my code receives.